# Twitter4j : Send Direct Messages to more than 250 followers

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to develop an app where a user can share messages and urls using twitter4j.

i can't use `mTwitter.updateStatus(message);` as it tweets to all followers whereas i want it to be for selected followers, i will have to go for:

```
 DirectMessage message = sender.sendDirectMessage(recipientId, message);
```

which again is limited to 250 per account regardless of the number of followers we do have. But the trouble here is the user needs to do this sharing to his friends and that too many times.

As the twitter has put a limit of 250 direct messages, i think it may not be feasible to do so.

Do we have any way around with this?

Thanks in Advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no workaround for this. Twitter limits can not be bypassed by any means, either through API or web scraping.

Though recently I have observed that some verified twitter account are able to send a multicast direct message to all their followers. One of my friends got a DM via a verified twitter account he was following which had 350K followers. On confirming with a few more of my friends and people belonging to the organization itself which owned that twitter acount, it was confirmed that the message was sent to all the followers.
But this is no where documented by twitter and seems that this facility is available to only a few verified twitter accounts.